Why do I have to uncheck "Delegate IDE build/run actions to Maven" to run my Scala program in IDEA?

Each time I check "Delegate IDE build/run actions to Maven," my Scala program ends up like this.
enter image description here
If it's just a simple HelloWorld program and your pom.xml has nothing in it, then it's odd that you encounter this issue.
enter image description here
Then try unchecking "Delegate IDE build/run actions to Maven" and see if that resolves the issue.
enter image description here

Program runs normally.
enter image description here
My Scala version is 2.11.8, and JDK version is 1.8.181.
enter image description here
Although I've double-checked the JDK and Scala SDK in the Project Structure multiple times, I'm still concerned about unchecking "Delegate IDE build/run actions to Maven" because I might need to use Maven for packaging in the future.
